# Installing TinyGo results in Command Line Tools (CLT) SDK folder names mismatch on macOS

Tags: go, xcode-command-line-tools, tinygo

When following the [TinyGo Quick Install Guide for macOS](https://tinygo.org/getting-started/install/macos/) I'm running into the following error: `Error: The contents of the SDKs in your Command Line Tools (CLT) installation do not match the SDK folder names.`

```bash
% brew install tinygo
==> Installing tinygo from tinygo-org/tools
Error: The contents of the SDKs in your Command Line Tools (CLT) installation do not match the SDK folder names.
A clean reinstall of Command Line Tools (CLT) should fix this.
```

The full install instructions are just two commands:

```bash
% brew tap tinygo-org/tools
% brew install tinygo
```

The CLT are currently installed in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` as shown by `xcode-select --print-path`:

```bash
% xcode-select --print-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

`pkgutil` shows I have the latest install:

```bash
% pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
version: 13.4.0.0.1.1651278267
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1654474872
groups: com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group
```

Reinstalling Command Line Tools results in the path being the same and confirmed in this article "[How to Install Command Line Tools in Mac OS X (Without Xcode)](https://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/)". Where does TinyGo want the Command Line Tools to be installed and how can it be installed there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyGo's installer for macOS requires Command Line Tools to be installed in the alternate location used when Xcode is fully installed (not just the Command Line Tools): `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

After installing Xcode (much larger package than just the CLT), `xcode-select` will show the alternate location which enables TinyGo to be installed:

```bash
% xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```